Safari won't stop caching my React App using node js http.createServer, NGINX
I have a React application that has been in production for quite a while. Monday evening we released a new update and now any of our users running Safari 16.x or older is unable to use the application they are presented with just a white page and chunk load errors.
enter image description here
If I have the users do a hard refresh (command + r) it loads the page, however on subsequent loads it still uses the cached version.
enter image description here
I thought I could fix this by adding headers for Cache-Control and then telling the users to hard refresh their browser.
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log('Path : ', path.join(__dirname, 'build'));
        return handler(req, res, {
        public: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        cleanUrls: true,
        rewrites: [
            {source: '/**', destination: '/index.html'},
        ],
        headers: [
            {
                source: "/index.html",
                headers: [{
                key: "Cache-Control",
                value: "no-cache"
            }]
        }],
        directoryListing: false,
    });
});

I'm obviously missing something here and any help would be greatly appreciated.
